# Adding Array Elements

Tags: c#, arrays

i'm attempting to learn C# and I have this code. I want it to display a random list of integers and then add them all together within the array and then display the average of all the numbers. Where have I gone wrong, can anyone help? Thanks.

```
using System;

class grades
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int sumValue = 0;
        int[] grades = new int [ 30 ];
        Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        grades[i] = rnd.Next(1,101);

    foreach (int i in grades)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", i);
        sumValue = sumValue + i;
        }

    double average = sumValue/30;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", average); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, what *exactly* behaves unexpectedly? can you be explicit?

Comment: Yeah, the random integers are displayed but the adding and the average isn't calculated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Yeah, the random integers are displayed but the adding and the average isn't calculated.

Yes, it is; you can make it more obvious:

```
double average = sumValue / 30.0;
Console.WriteLine("The average is: {0:##0.0}", average);
```

Note also the `.0` which ensures we aren't doing integer arithmetic (different fraction / rounding rules).

Comment: Thank you. Just me being stupid and forgetting to make it stand out. Thanks.